# Why is this code not giving any duplicates?

Tags: vba, random

I was looking for a lottery number generator and I found this:

```
Sub LotteyCode()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim xNumbers(49) As Integer
On Error Resume Next
For xy = 1 To 10000
Set WorkRng = Range("A" & xy)
For xIndex = 1 To 49
xNumbers(xIndex) = xIndex
Next
For xIndex = 1 To 6
xNum = 1 + Application.Round(Rnd * (49 - xIndex), 0)
WorkRng.Offset(0, xIndex - 1).Value = xNumbers(xNum)
xNumbers(xNum) = xNumbers(50 - xIndex)
Next
Next xy
End Sub
```

I read through the code and for the life of me I cannot understand how this is NOT generating duplicate numbers (the code didn't come with explanation on why it was written like this)...

I ran 10000 iterations (as you can see by the "xy = 1 To 10000") to make sure it really is giving unique numbers.

If anyone can shed some light on this, I would be most greatful!

Comment: This is Fisher-Yates-Knuth shuffle, I believe, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was actually a little confused at first as well but after I walked through it, I noticed that what makes it work is the first and third lines below:

```
xNum = 1 + Application.Round(Rnd * (49 - xIndex), 0)
WorkRng.Offset(0, xIndex - 1).Value = xNumbers(xNum)
xNumbers(xNum) = xNumbers(50 - xIndex)
```

The first line picks a random index from the array but on each iteration, **excludes an additional index from the end** of the array.

The second line "picks" (in the lotto sense) the number at that index in the array.

The third line **replaces the value at the chosen index** with the number that was excluded from that iteration ensuring that the number chosen on that iteration cannot be chosen again.

Comment: This is Fisher-Yates-Knuth shuffle.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: I have 2 additional questions...
1. You say that: "picks a random index from the array but on each iteration, excludes an additional index from the end of the array." - Am I missing something in the code? It just looks like a complicated random number picker...
2. You say that: "replaces the value at the chosen index with the number that was excluded from that iteration ensuring that the number chosen on that iteration cannot be chosen again." - How is replacing a chosen index's value make it impossible to be chosen again?
Thank you!

Comment: 1. It essentially _is_ a complicated random number picker but the complication is to ensure it picks a valid number from the list.  2. The number "picked" for the lotto is not the index but the **value** at that index.  By replacing each number after it is chosen, even if that **index** is chosen again, the result is a different **value** being picked.  Check out explanation of the [modern method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Modern_method) at the link provided by @SeverinPappadeux .  It has an example and is clearer than what I started to write.